# Why isn't this Laravel controller working how I want it too?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a CSS edit if a there isn't a group in the database to display, because when there isn't a group underneath the "Add Group" button, the button doesn't have a bottom border. Sorry if I'm going about this completely wrong, I'm new to Laravel and PHP for that matter.

[image]

[image]

```
if(DB::table('forum_groups')->where('author_id')->first() >= 0) {
            echo('
            <style type="text/css">
            a.btn.btn-default {
                border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
                border-bottom: none;
            }
            </style>
            ');
} else {}
```

Comment: You try to compare an object with 0, don't do that. Watch some stuff on laracasts.com to help you get started, becuase all this looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of by doing this way ... you can create a special css class and alot it to your tag and you can set the value from controller to view by doing

```
return View::make(your.page)->with('value',$value)
```

In view you can just check for example

your custom css is like

```
       .bottom_border {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom: none;
        }
```

and in button for example you can do like

```
<button class="btn btn-default {{ !empty($value) ? 'bottom_border' : '' }}">add Group </button>
```

where $value is the groups fetched by you if groups exists above code will add that class to your tag, if not it will not.

I hope this will help you.